# Is it possible to query Google analytics API with microsoft Power Query?

Tags: excel, google-analytics

I would like to pull google analytics data with microsoft Power Query into Excel. I have tested using "Get external data from Web", writing the URL from Google's Query explorer, but I can not manage to authenticate myself. Has anybody tried this?
Thanks for the help, Ruth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible now.

With the current version of the Power Query plugin you can authenticate through oAuth with your Google Analytics account and query the data via the GA API without writing code.

Comment: you can also use http://www.scitylana.com (analytics backwards) for unsampled and clickstream extraction with no dimensional limits

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i've made a Power Query application that can query data from Google Analytics Api.

You can find this app on github: 
https://github.com/40-02/GoogleAnalyticsViaPowerQueryForExcel

And you can find video how this app works here:
https://vimeo.com/maximuvarov/googleanalyticsviapowerqueryformsexcel

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.  I realize that's hard in this case...

Comment: Hi Maxim, first of all Thanks.
I have followed the steps up to "From Authentication Code to Access Token" where you talked about powershell and json. I am not familiar with powershell, so I am not sure how to do those steps.
Could you develop that part a bit more?
Thanks,
Ruth

Comment: Hi Ruth, 
I'm working on updated version of such file that could work withouth power shell or vba. 
I've almost finished this. As soon as I finish it - I'll publish my version here. Please wait for a while.

Comment: Absolutely, that would be perfect, thanks. Many, many thanks. :) Ruth

Comment: Ruth, if you still interested, I've made the application that works. You can find it on my improved answer. Thanks